# After updating RecyclerView library from 23.3.0 to 24.2.0, getting java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I am using couple of RecyclerView around my app. I wanted to update support library I've been using which was 23.3.0 to 24.2.0 and suddenly app started to crash with the java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException error. 
Stack trace points to my base activity classes onResume method. 
Here is the stack trace:

Failed to submit events task

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@ac47c5f rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@40816ac[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 5]
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:298)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:503)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.submit(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:602)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:593)
                                                       at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.executeAsync(AnswersEventsHandler.java:182)
                                                       at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.processEvent(AnswersEventsHandler.java:168)
                                                       at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersEventsHandler.processEventAsync(AnswersEventsHandler.java:44)
                                                       at com.crashlytics.android.answers.SessionAnalyticsManager.onLifecycle(SessionAnalyticsManager.java:128)
                                                       at com.crashlytics.android.answers.AnswersLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityStarted(AnswersLifecycleCallbacks.java:26)
                                                       at io.fabric.sdk.android.ActivityLifecycleManager$ActivityLifecycleCallbacksWrapper$1.onActivityStarted(ActivityLifecycleManager.java:111)
                                                       at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(Application.java:223)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.onStart(Activity.java:1245)
                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:592)
                                                       at com.myApp.base.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:173)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1234)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6329)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

here is my build.gradle sdk versions

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and google related dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
```

Do you have any idea why I might be facing the problem?

Comment: Post all your build.gradle files

Comment: Please post your code of `com.myApp.base.BaseActivity`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343563/avoiding-rejectedexecutionexception-in-android-4-4-when-app-uses-list